# Запуск docker-compose из другой директории

Tags: docker-compose, context

Есть docker-compose файл, работать с которым я бы хотел из другой директории. Нашёл -f флаг, но при таком использовании он не видет переменные окружения .env, а многие вещи в композ файле ссылаются на эти переменные. Как решается такая проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Следует использовать `context` или явно указывай путь к переменным. Если работа ведётся с `context`, указывайте пути относительно того места, куда его выставляете. Например, запускаемся из корня:

```
docker-compose -f .deploy/docker-compose.full.yml up
```

Тогда, чтобы контекст указывал на то место, откуда запускаемся, нужно сделать что-то в духе:

```
grader-v2-grader-v2-front-admin:
    build:
        context: ..
        dockerfile: .deploy/Dockerfile
    network_mode: host
```